# iSMS folder in the SD Card

Tags: file-management

I recently installed the app 'Empty Folder Cleaner' from playstore. On running the app, I noticed that the majority of empty folders removed were from the parent folder called iSMS, in my external SD Card. Inside the parent folder, the empty folders were images, videos, etc. Does anyone have any idea regarding that? Is it some sort of a mischievous thing?

P.S - I'm running on Android 4.2.2(rooted), Sony Xperia C2305.

Comment: There are several apps named "iSMS" in Play Store, could you provide a link to which one do you use, or have used before? (I probably already know the answer, but I need some clarification)

Answer (score 0):

- Use an application backup app to backup all your apps,(App Backup and Restore) is one app that i know of.
- uninstall all the apps from your phone, (Please be careful and remove only the apps that you installed yourself, removing system apps could prove problematic)
- delete the Folder that you dont want on the sd card, like the iSMS folder you said
- restart your phone.
- start all apps that you have on your phone, (you have removed all apps, the only ones remain are system apps)
- check if the folder was created in your storage media.
- if it was, then there is a system app creating the folder.
- if not, then one of the 3rd party apps downloaded from the play store are creating this folder
- all apps having the "modify and delete contents of your sd card" can create folders in your sd card, during reinstallation, check the app permissions carefully.
- installing each one by one and.opening and checking the sd card for the folder, you will eventually find the culprit app.